# What is the plot of ST1 Up the Garden Path

Tags: odnd

So I recently saw a couple copies of ST1: Up the Garden Path become available through a used game store I frequent.  This lead me to wondering what exactly was it's plot?  As an aside has anyone ever reviewed the module?  (Links appreciated naturally!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly rare; here's the only informative thing I found with a quick search:

http://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/modpages/st.html

You may just be out of luck when it comes to getting more detail, due to its rarity. A copy in good condition sold for $2000.

Comment: I'd seen this, the summary is frustratingly vague!  One would think for a 16 page adventure that there would be a little more info available.  I guess maybe it's doomed to be collected and never read/played.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently my Googling skills need refining as with a little bit more research I found this: [More On ST1 Up The Garden Path](http://blog.retroroleplaying.com/2011/10/more-on-st1-up-garden-path-1986-tsr-uk.html)